# Adding tags to every word except non characters outside angle brackets

Tags: java, html, regex

I'm working on text paragraph that contains image tags and new line tags. the objective is to make everything nonword charechter been shown clearly by changing all word charachter's color to white.
I'm using java as programming language.
I'm tring to use regular expression but the **problem** is **it changes word charechters inside image tags.**

```
String RegEx = "\\w|[àÀâÂäÄáÁéÉèÈêÊëËìÌîÎïÏòÒôÔöÖùÙûÛüÜçÇ’ñ]";

try {
    Pattern mypattern = Pattern.compile(RegEx, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher myMatcher = mypattern.matcher(sentence);
    int offset = 0;
    while (myMatcher.find()) {
        int start = myMatcher.start() + offset;
        int end = myMatcher.end() + offset;
        sentence = sentence.substring(0, start) + "<font color=\"white\">" + sentence.substring(start, end) + "</font>" + sentence.substring(end, sentence.length());
        offset += 28;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

example of the needed result.
input:
`Most implementations<img title="hello:" alt="hello:{}" src="http://images.doctissimo.fr/hello.gif" class="wysiwyg_smiley" /> provide ASDF as a module, and you can simply (require "asdf").`

output:

```
<font color="white">Most<font> <font color="white">implementations<font><img title="hello:" alt="hello:{}" src="http://images.doctissimo.fr/hello.gif" class="wysiwyg_smiley" /> <font color="white">provide<font> <font color="white">ASDF<font> <font color="white">as<font> <font color="white">a<font> <font color="white">module<font>, <font color="white">and<font> <font color="white">you<font> <font color="white">can<font> <font color="white">simply<font> (<font color="white">require<font> "<font color="white">asdf<font>").
```

Comment: Use an HTML parser/producer!

Comment: You can't parse HTML with RegEx. Every time you try, a omnipotent abstract and religion-independent entity kills a kitten.

Comment: Can you please look at JSoup. It may help you.
http://jsoup.org/

Comment: @Kroltan Great, you just made my day. ;)

Comment: Have a look to this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21731443/363573

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NOTA:**

> I hope this discussion will be an help for the casual reader and/or
>   googler and will be "a window of peace" in the war of **Regex vs HTML
>   Parser**.

---

### Solution #1: With Regex

#### Sample code

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String []args){
        String sentence = "Most implementations<img title=\"hello:\" alt=\"hello:{}\" src=\"http://images.doctissimo.fr/hello.gif\" class=\"wysiwyg_smiley\" /> provide ASDF as a module, and you can simply (require \"asdf\").";
        String RegEx = "(?is)(\\w+|[\u00E0\u00C0\u00E2\u00C2\u00E4\u00C4\u00E1\u00C1\u00E9\u00C9\u00E8\u00C8\u00EA\u00CA\u00EB\u00CB\u00EC\u00CC\u00EE\u00CE\u00EF\u00CF\u00F2\u00D2\u00F4\u00D4\u00F6\u00D6\u00F9\u00D9\u00FB\u00DB\u00FC\u00DC\u00E7\u00C7\u2019\u00F1]+)(<[^>]+>)?";

        Pattern mypattern = Pattern.compile(RegEx);

        Matcher myMatcher = mypattern.matcher(sentence);
        String output=myMatcher.replaceAll("<font color=\"white\">$1</font>$2");

        System.out.println(output);
     }
}
```

#### Output

```
<font color="white">Most</font> <font color="white">implementations</font> <img title="hello:" alt="hello:{}" src="http://images.doctissimo.fr/hello.gif" class="wysiwyg_smiley" /> <font color="white">provide</font> <font color="white">ASDF</font> <font color="white">as</font> <font color="white">a</font> <font color="white">module</font>, <font color="white">and</font> <font color="white">you</font> <font color="white">can</font> <font color="white">simply</font> (<font color="white">require</font> "<font color="white">asdf</font>").
```

---

### Solution #2: With Jsoup

#### Sample code

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;

public class HelloWorldWithJsoup {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence = "Most implementations<img title=\"hello:\" alt=\"hello:{}\" src=\"http://images.doctissimo.fr/hello.gif\" class=\"wysiwyg_smiley\" /> provide ASDF as a module, and you can simply (require \"asdf\").";

        Element body = Jsoup.parse(sentence).body();

        for (TextNode textNode : body.textNodes()) {
            textNode.wrap("<font color=\"white\"></font>");
        }

        System.out.println(body.html());
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
<font color="white">Most implementations</font>
<img title="hello:" alt="hello:{}" src="http://images.doctissimo.fr/hello.gif" class="wysiwyg_smiley" />
<font color="white"> provide ASDF as a module, and you can simply (require &quot;asdf&quot;).</font>
```

---

### Discussion

Let's compare both approaches:

#### Quantitatively

Except the imports, both codes share the same lines of code count. Excluding the core classes offered by the JDK and classes instanciated under the cover, Solution#2 needs 3 additional classes (`Jsoup`, `Element` and `TextNode`) while Solution#1 needs 2 (`Matcher`,`Pattern`). Solution#2 requires that you put a dependency inside your code while Solution#1 is ready out of box with a JDK.

#### Qualitatively

From the readability point of view, they are both straight forward. However for a non seasoned Java regex API reader, it may be challenging to understand the code. From a maintenability point of view, the regex used here is quite long and you need unicode capabilities. The Jsoup solution relies only on well documented methods. Finally, the output produced by Jsoup is more respectful of HTML good practices. Less `font` tags are used.

#### Comparison matrix

```
Quantitatively:     |  Regex vs Jsoup
--------------------------------------
Lines of code       |    O        O
Classes used        |    O        X
Dependency required |    O        X


Qualitatively:      |  Regex vs Jsoup
--------------------------------------
Readability         |    O        O
Maintenability      |    X        O
HTML good practices |    X        O
```

As you can see, the battle ends up with a **draw**.

#### Conclusion

IMO, in this use case, choosing between one solution or another will **greatly** depend on the **produced** result by each solution AND the **expected** result. The Jsoup solution draws characters like `,` or `)` in white. The regex approach doesn't. For the final user, which output is desired will lead towards one solution or another.

Comment: @user3292991 Which solution did you choose ?

Comment: I chose the regex solution because the objective of my work is to clarify the non-word charterers.

Comment: In what way is that regex at all readable?  Do you have all those unicode code points memorized?